# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString while trying to share image to social media intent Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, twitter

Hello I'm trying to enable my android app to post an image made from the app to facebook or twitter or instagram. I copied an exact example from someone else and it still doesn't work.

```
public void ShareToSocialMedia(String application) {
Bitmap b =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),            
R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setPackage(application);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
        b, "Title", null);
 Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
  }
```

I'm getting an error at the line

```
    Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
```

and I don't know why. can someone show me how to resolve this please?

Comment: What is the value of `path`. Try Logging the value of `path`.

Comment: the value of path is MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
        b, "Title", null);

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [`Uri.parse`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)), you'll see that it throws a `NullPointerException` if the passed `uriString` is `null`.

Then looking at the [`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html) method that you depend on to obtain the `uriString`, the documentation states that it returns `null` if the image failed to be stored for any reason.

Now, as to what that reason is, your guess is as good as mine, but a [search on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage+null) does reveal that there are people experiencing similar issues.

Comment: Ahh, I found out why it's saying it is null. so the method MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage accesses the external memory but when your phone is plugged into the computer, the external memory gets blocked... so basically you would run this without being plugged in (which what you what normally use an app)